# Change server port in application properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to change the server port.

I've written an application properties file: https://github.com/Kifsif/reusable/tree/master/src/main/resources

And in it:

```
server.port=8083
```

But I get this error:

```
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

How can I start at 8083?

Comment: actually you did right one. **server.port = 8083**  is the answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be working on 8083, but if it is complaining about 8080 just kill it, so it stops compalning about 8080 and if there is any error it would be related to 8083

1. run CMD as admin
2. netstat -a -o -n
3. find PID of process on 8080
4. kill it using command "taskkill /F /PID xxxx"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdH6MvnGNpU&ab_channel=Seeofgames

Comment: But don't want to kill what is running at the port. I want to change the port.

Comment: Maybe try to restart your machine and reimport your project? It might be a caching issue and it does not recognize your changes for ports. I mean its common sense, you want to run it on 8083 you don't really care about other ports.